# Error trying to PUT edgeNGram tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic 1.5 on Amazon EWS.

So I am simply trying to put the following analyzer and tokenizer but getting back an error:

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {            
            "my_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
{
  "error": "IndexCreationException[[pictures_testing] failed to create index]; 
  nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer type [null] or tokenizer for [tokenizer]]; ",
  "status": 400
```

}

I have tried various permutations but nothing has yet worked.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your tokenizer up one level:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edgeNGram"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, couldn't see the wood for the trees on this one!